# Increase max connection pool size for Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, urllib

I am using Python Selenium with a ChromeDriver to automate stuff in multiple threads but it seems my tasks are heavy enough to reach the default max pool size of urllib3 and I keep geting this warning:

```
urllib3.connectionpool WARNING - Connection pool is full, discarding connection with IP 127.0.0.1
```

I can't find where is the max pool size value set in the Selenium package files.

I've found https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#customizing-pool-behavior but I can't find where does Selenium set the max poolsize in its files.

Did someone face this before?